# Ubuntu not resolving local domain

Tags: localhost, systemd-resolved

I have setup a wordpress blog on my raspberry pi. I can access it normally from my windows pc and mobile but the local domain is not resolving on ubuntu which I installed in virtualbox.

I tried to access my local domain using kali linux which is also installed in virtual box and the local domain is working fine.

How to resolve local domain resolve issue in ubuntu?

Update - i was able to access my local domain from ubuntu after editing "/etc/hosts" file and adding my local domains ip address.

Why I wasn't able to access the local domain before making this change?

Comment: What is *local domain*? How have you configured DNS entries?

Comment: Are you talking about accessing addresses like `http://myblog.local` ?

Comment: yes. I can access local domain like http://myblog from all the pc and mobile. But I can't access the local domain only from ubuntu.